# Syntax variants for functions and predicates in first-order logic

Tags: first-order-logic

There seem to be at least three syntactic conventions in common use for function terms and predicate formulas in first-order languages. Specifically (where $\mathfrak{F}$ is an arbitrary function or predicate symbol):

- $x \mathfrak{F} y$
- $\mathfrak{F} x y$
- $\mathfrak{F}(x, y)$

Sometimes a single convention for, say, binary predicates isn't followed consistently even within the same book.

This brings up a few related questions:

1. Besides the three listed above, are there any other syntactic variants to be aware of that are in common use in first-order languages of mathematical logic? (*reverse* Polish notation might hypothetically be one, but I've never seen it used in first-order logic)
2. Is any one of these syntactic conventions more "officially correct" than the others? (my guess would be that $\mathfrak{F} x y$ is kind of the "canonical" one, but I'm not at all sure).
3. In the case of the $\mathfrak{F}(x, y)$ syntax, the comma symbol `,` seems to pretty clearly have special meaning as an argument separator. Yet in the books where I've seen this syntax used, the definition of the "alphabet" of first-order languages never mentions `,` as a special symbol (alongside the other special symbols like parentheses and $\neg$ and $\wedge$). I guess this is just an oversight? Or am I misunderstanding something?
4. Bonus question: I would have thought that books covering mathematical logic would make clear the syntactic issues like the preceding 1-3, but (surprisingly) I have yet to find one that does. Does anyone know of such a book (or other resource like lecture notes)?

   - Books I've looked at are: Logic books by Ebbinghaus and Enderton, and *Discovering Modern Set Theory* by Just & Weese.

Comment: Not an "official one": each book must specify its own syntax. Having said that, the syntax $P(x,y,z)$ is the most frequently used, due to its readibility. $xPy$ is suitable only for binary relations: compare $n < m$ with $<(n,m)$.

Comment: Also "," is used for readibility: consider e.g. $<(123)$. Is it $1 < 12$ or $12 < 3$?

Comment: Thanks, this helps clarify

Comment: Ebbinghaus is IMO quite detailed wrt syntax (see the "calculus" for terms and that for formulas).

Comment: If a book uses commas without specifying it as an auxiliary symbol, that's an oversight, yes.

Comment: Books on proof theory or computational aspects of logic tend to be much more precise regarding syntactic matters than books with a model theoretic emphasis like Ebbinghaus et al.  If you're interested in these syntactic matters  you might look at  Restall's 'Introduction to Substructural Logic', Schwichtenberg / Troelstra's 'Basic Proof Theory', Hindley's 'Basic Simple Type Theory' and Ranta's 'Type-Theoretical Grammar.' The latter two are on different kinds of type theory, but type theories enjoy an intimate connection with proof theory.